# Why the User model doesn't need a has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In "[Rails 3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/katz/)" Chapter 6, Section 6.5.1, we associated a ticket to a user by using:

```
@ticket = @project.tickets.build(params[:id].merge!(:user => current_user))
```

and the `Ticket` model has this directive: `belongs_to :user`, then it all works.

But, why does the `User` model not need the `has_many :tickets` to build a "one-to-many" association between user and topic?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no `has_many` in the user model

`@user.topics` will definitely not work unless you have the `has_many :topics` set in the User model.

Just the same way `@topic.user` will not work unless you have set the `belongs_to :user` in the Topic model.

Comment: yes, there is no `has_many :tickets` in User model, and i also check the source provided by the book press